# How can I solve this infinite exponent tower?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, power-towers

Using calculus (or algebra), how would I solve an infinite exponent tower such as this?

$$c_0x^{c_1x^{c_2x^{c_3x^{.^{.^.}}}}}=a$$

Where $c_0=1$ and $c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n}{2}$ for $n=0,1,\ldots$ and $a>0$.

Comment: [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is much nicer than HTML for math formatting.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to know the result of the expression for $x=1$?

Comment: As $1^\text{any thing}=1$, the answer is $a=1$.

Comment: No, just a general formula to solve for 'x', with regards to a constant 'a'

Comment: @YamB I edited your posted to avoid the ambiguities above, please check that it is really what you want.

Comment: Note that $c_n = 2^{-n}$.